# Detect if script was started from GUI or SSH-login

Tags: bash

How can I in a bash script detect if the bash-script was started from.

The main GUI/keyboard/mouse (possibly including VNC) 
**or**
 
if it was started in some other way,

such as via an SSH terminal connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, reliably. What you should be doing is checking for a value in `$DISPLAY` and running in GUI mode if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

You could check a few variables, especially those starting with `SSH_`. On my setup, which runs under the ssh-agent, the following are set:

```
SSH_CLIENT='127.0.0.1 43547 22'
SSH_CONNECTION='127.0.0.1 43547 127.0.0.1 22'
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/7
```